# Migration Issue - EF thinks database needs updating, projects referencing it won't run

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So during the last week I've added several Migrations to my MVC portal project.

Something came up which meant I had to rollback a specific migration.

My recent migration history:

```
201506101200157_userPermissions
201508181440262_API1
201508201305341_ContactUpdate
201508241312425_ApiLog
201508271518402_ActivityLog
```

The migration I needed to negate was `ContactUpdate`, and I did something stupid to acheive this. Rather than simply making the changes and adding a new migration I rolled back to `API1`, deleted the `ContactUpdate` migration, then re-updated back to `ActivityLog`.

This seemed to work fine and my portal runs fine, I get no errors about the database in this project. But when I run add-migration now the up method is basically the down method from `ContactUpdate`, i.e. it still thinks it needs to revert to accommodate the changes that I made.

The `ContactUpdate` migration involved adding two fields to my Contact table. So in summary this is the order of action I took:

- Roll back to API1
- Delete ContactUpdate migration
- Update-Database to latest migration
- Delete two fields from Contact class

So it's fairly obvious why EF thinks it needs to drop these two columns as I deleted them after the last update.

A project I have that references this MVC project is now throwing an error

> The model backing the  context has changed since the database was created

I put it down to this issue of EF believing my database needs updating despite total cohesion between the DB and my code. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have any data in your database that you cannot re-seed?

Comment: @TomasLycken yeah I do

Comment: OK. I don't know a way to resolve the issue then (at least not from the top of my head), but I strongly recommend you take a backup *now* ;)

Comment: @TomasLycken and out of interest, if I answered no? Already backed up.

Comment: If you had no unsalvageable, important data in the database, you could just wipe it and run all the migration scripts from scratch. That would build a database that is in sync with your EF code first model, without confusing itself with outdated snapshots of the model. However, you might then have to do some manual work to recover the data from your backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use your source control to get the migration back and do it properly? i.e. add a new migration after `ActivityLog` which undoes `ContactUpdate`?

If not, you can add a blank migration. This will include a snapshot of your current model and store it in the migrations history table. Doing this should kick everything back in line. Run `Add-Migration` and delete the contents of the `Up` and `Down` methods.

NB I'm sure you already know this, but for the benefit of anyone else who comes across this answer in the future I'm not recommending blank migrations as a usual workflow, only for correcting mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tim. Tried to implement but now add-migration throws an error `Unable to generate an explicit migration because the following explicit migrations are pending:` then lists all of my migrations. Update-Database throws an error:`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.`....

Comment: check your web.config connectionstring property. (or any other place in which your dbcontext looks for connectionstring)

Comment: What actions did you take since posting the question? Is this error thrown when you're trying to get your original migration back, or when you're trying to add a blank one? The `add-migration` error sounds like your `__MigrationHistory` table is empty.

If you're trying to get the original migration back, you'll need to roll back migrations to `API1`, then restore the deleted migration, then `update-database` to run them all (including `ContactUpdate`). You should then be able to add a new migration to drop the columns.

Comment: Don't laugh...but the problem was that I switched my startup project, and package manager consoles default project drop down apparently means nothing if the project isn't your startup project... So I went off on a little debugging adventure for half an hour. I'll try your suggestions now @Tim

Comment: @Tim adding the blank Migration has solved the issue of EF's confusion, now when I add a migration it is empty, so they seem to be on the same page. Unfortunately this hasn't solved the larger problem I thought it was responsible for. The project which references this project and uses my DbContext class still receives a `The model backing the context has changed since the database was created` error. I guess that's something for another question.

Comment: You've presumably restarted your projects so they're both running the latest version of your code? Are there any other projects using EF migrations?

Comment: Only one project uses migrations in my solution. They're running the latest version. I even decompiled the dll in my bin folder to check the DbContext class was correct. It's certainly a strange one.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably worth another question then. Sounds intriguing though!

Comment: Thanks for your help! It may have not solved the real issue but as a side task this one was really confusing me despite being so simple.